# How to implement a FrameLayout on a custom view - android

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

I'm looking to draw a listView to the screen once the player loses my game. How do I lay the listView over my custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to probably include the ListView in your Activity layout as the last child contained in the FrameLayout. You can set the `visibility` attribute of the ListView to `gone` or `invisible` and simply toggle this attribute using the `setVisibility` method when the player has lost the game.